# File transformations before packaging WSP

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, debugging, packaging, staging

I need to modify the content of some files in my SP 2010 project before packaging, something like [Web.Config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx).

I need a file to have different content based on the environment: Debug, Staging, Release.

What are my options aside pre-build event command line in the build events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually used [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) to intervene before the WSP packaging step ([step 3 from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231560)).

What you will need is the  `AfterLayout` step. An explanation on [Integrating post-processors in SharePoint builds](http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=335) you can find here.